# Insert or update campaign member after if condition

Tags: apex, query, class, if

I'm trying to check if a campaign member has already been entered in a campaign in case affemative update the status otherwise enter the member.

This is my code, but currently it doesn't work very well (does not perform the campaign member update) :

```
List<CampaignMember> controlAlreadyInserted = [Select id,Status 
                 from CampaignMember 
                 where ContactId=:c.Id and CampaignId =:camp.Id];
system.debug(controlAlreadyInserted);
if(controlAlreadyInserted.size()<=0){
            
   CampaignMember cm= New CampaignMember(CampaignId=camp.Id,
                                         ContactId=c.Id,
                                         Status='To send');
   memberList.add(cm);
   system.debug(memberList);
        
   insert memberList;
}
else{
   controlAlreadyInserted.Status='Sent';
   update controlAlreadyInserted;
}
```

Are there additional alternatives to be able to get it to work properly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384936/edit) your question to elaborate on what you mean by "it doesn't work very well" (e.g., *exact* error text, exactly how it is not working as expected). *(Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center where, among other things, it says that your question should include, 'A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help).')*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite this a bit

```
List<CampaignMember> matchingCampaignMembers = [Select id,Status 
                 from CampaignMember 
                 where ContactId=:c.Id and CampaignId =:camp.Id];
if(matchingCampaignMembers.isEmpty()){
            
   insert new CampaignMember(CampaignId=camp.Id,
                             ContactId=c.Id,
                             Status='To send');
}
else{
   for (CampaignMember matchingCampaignMember : matchingCampaignMembers) {
       matchingCampaignMember.Status='Sent';
   }
   update matchingCampaignMembers;
}
```

Now, since a given contact can exist only once on a given campaign, we could also do this:

```
List<CampaignMember> matchingCampaignMembers = [Select id,Status 
                 from CampaignMember 
                 where ContactId=:c.Id and CampaignId =:camp.Id];
if(matchingCampaignMembers.isEmpty()){
            
   insert new CampaignMember(CampaignId=camp.Id,
                             ContactId=c.Id,
                             Status='To send');
}
else{
   update new CampaignMember(
     Id = matchingCampaignMembers[0].Id,
     Status = 'to send');
}
```